# R: Merge duplicate matches horizontally

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes and have multiple matches append horizontally:

dataset1:

```
id
1 email1
1 email1b
2 email2
3 email3
```

dataset2:

```
id name
1 bob
2 rob
3 kat
```

I would like to use merge to combine these dataframes on id. When there are duplicate matches with id 1, I would like merge by "id" to return both results horizontally:

```
id name email 
1 bob email1 email1b
2 rob email2
3 kat email3
```

It doesn't seem like merge can do this, it creates multiple rows for duplicate values. Any other ideas?

Thanks! 
-R newbie

Comment: edited above to be more accurate- cbind will not work in this instance.

Comment: For your updated dataset1, is it one column or two columns? (as i didn't find the column name for email) . I just updated with a modified solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UpdateNew

Assuming that the first dataset have two columns,

```
dat1 <- read.table(text="id email
1 email1
1 email1b
2 email2
3 email3",sep="",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

dat2 <- read.table(text="id name
1 bob
2 rob
3 kat",sep="",header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

res <- aggregate(email~., data=merge(dat1, dat2, by="id"), FUN=paste, collapse=" ")
res[order(res$id),]
#   id name          email
#  1  1  bob email1 email1b
#  3  2  rob         email2
#  2  3  kat         email3
```

- `merge` the two datasets by `id`
- `aggregate` on the merged dataset so the emails belonging to the same `ids` are pasted horizontally in a row.

Comment: I cant rely on cbind since I have duplicate ids. Is there something else that will match on id and append in columns?

Comment: @user3813578. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
email <- c("email1", "email1b", "email2", "email3")
uid <- unique(id) 
data.frame(id=uid,email=unlist(lapply(uid,function(x) paste(email[x==id],collapse=' '))))
```